# CD/CI with jenkins + github

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

Today, we´re using GitHub as our code repository and Jenkins to run the builds and deploy our apps in AWS.
But the process is quite complex because we have to open a PR to merge our branches into develop, after another one to merge develop into release and other one to merge release into master.

Is there any way to automatically merge into release branch when a push is made into develop?
It´d make our life here much easier.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/triggering-jenkins-build-on-push-using-github-webhooks-52d4361542d4) (or any other tutorial) to set up triggering a Jenkins build on a push. Then in the build triggered by the push, you can use the GitHub REST API to [create](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request) and then [merge](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/pulls#merge-a-pull-request) a PR. It might also be possible to merge directly without a PR.

Comment: thanks for the help...I like the option to merge directly without a PR...how could I do that in jenkinsfile ?